# Own function (round for NSString) in NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nspredicate

I got problem with NSPredicate.

I got predicate:

```
NSPredicate* pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FUNCTION('12.12345','round',3) = 12.123"];
```

and defined extension for NSString:

```
-(double) round:(NSNumber*) precision;
```

When I call manually:

```
NSLog(@"%f",[s round:3])
```

where s is NSString, it's working prefectly, but used in NSPredicate rise:
NSInvalidArgumentException: rease -[NSCFString round]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I use solution used on page: http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2922267976/using-custom-functions-with-nsexpression

The main question is to make round function in NSPredicate, so any other solutions are welcome

Comment: The solution is:

    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FUNCTION('12.12345','round:',3) = 12.123"]

and in extension class can't return base type.
Should be 

    -(NSNumber*) round:(NSString*) precision;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon (`:`) must be part of the selector in the `FUNCTION`, so it should be `FUNCTION('12.12345', 'round:', 3)`

Also, I believe the `round:` method should return an `NSNumber *`, not a primitive type.